# Re-order JSON attribute/value pairs using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    { 'Album': 'Dearest', 'Artist': 'Theresa Fu', 'Year': '2009'},
    { 'Album': 'To be Free', 'Artist': 'Arashi', 'Year': '2010'}
]
```

Goal is to do some simple re-ordering (not sorting) of the attribte / value pairs in the client via JavaScript. For example:

```
[
    { 'Album': 'Dearest', 'Year': '2009', 'Artist': 'Theresa Fu'},
    { 'Album': 'To be Free', 'Year': '2010' 'Artist': 'Arashi'}
]
```

Is there a simple way to this sort of work? Or, do I need to rip this apart on my own with JavaScript string functions and then stitch it back together (if so, any examples appreciated). FYI, at any given time I'll only be working with maybe 5 attributes and 10-15 rows of data, so low volume to be transformed.

Edit: Why am I doing this? I want to use the following JQuery Table plug-in:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?_Cl2jbzM

From what I gather, the order in which the columns are displayed in the grid must match the order of the attribute/value pairs in the JSON (I'll try and make sure)... I need to use a different order than what is stored in the payload.

Edit #2...And I was wrong. The plug-in does NOT rely on order, either. Didn't follow the cardinal rule of trying before I posted...assumed instead. Sorry guys.

Comment: Why do you need to? What problem are you trying to solve by reordering the properties? It really shouldn't matter what order they are in since you will retrieve them by name.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What is your higher level goal, that you think makes it necessary to order the properties in an object?

Comment: properties order in objects are not guaranted in JavaScript, so it's a bit useless isn't it ?

Comment: Note the docs on [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): `Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification.`

Comment: Also note the docs for JSON — An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
   pairs — http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Comment: though the standard says keys need not be ordered, every browser preserves order within that browser, so it's not useless at all. It would be useless to give up on something perfectly possible because of some paragraph in some book somewhere that contradicts billions of actual machines...

Comment: *"From what I gather, the order in which the columns are displayed in the grid must match the order of the attribute/value pairs in the JSON"* no, it looks like you specify the columns order with columns option.

Comment: OK, I no longer need to worry about solving this problem, as the plugin I'm dealing with his happy for the name/value pairs to be in any order. I'm good.

Comment: @dandavis: no, if you rely on browser specific behavior (which could change any time) then you are going to have a bad time. FWIW, chrome and Firefox order keys differently.

Comment: i said within each browser. who cares if between them it's different; neither will even know that and as far as any JS is concerned, the order "sticks" in that environment. if you somehow talks between browsers, lookout, and code something more robust, but i don't think that an issue for wiring up a grid... Also, the behavior likely won't change at any time, chrome tried to abandoned ordering and they got forced back to keeping up the defacto standard to keep scripts from breaking. maybe in ES6 strict...

Comment: @dandavis: Usually one writes code that runs in every browser. So, if you wanted to change the order of properties (if that was possible) you'd potentially have to write specific code for each browser.

Comment: hmm. the browsers i use put new keys last, know any that don't? and what about for node.js? would you consider it ok there because of the version control we have?

Comment: @dandavis: Chrome for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gk2j7/. It always puts numeric keys before non-numeric keys. The point is that the specification states that there is no guaranteed order of properties, so whatever the environment does is specific to the environment, and you should not make use of it (unless your OK with that your code might brake in the future or in other environments).

Comment: @FelixKling: i should have mentioned the numeric thing. thanks for taking the time to reply, good info. i'm well aware of the spec, but i also know what i've seen in the console for years, except that month or two chrome a few years ago... since ordering is widely assumed (correctly or not), we'll know if/when ordering changes because of the avalanche of complaints on SO about scripts that suddenly stopped working in fooBrowser vXX.

Comment: @dandavis: No, assuming the order will always be the same when the standard *explicitly* tells you it's not guaranteed is the height of folly. Besides anything else, why would you ever need them in some specific order anyway?

Comment: @MattBurland: "the height of folly" huh? i'm sure we can reach a little higher if we try ;)  the spec says keys don't have to be ordered, not that they aren't. This simply means we need to check our target environments to see what behavior they actually implement if we want to use this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Edit: Why am I doing this? I want to use the following JQuery Table plug-in:*
>
> http://www.jqueryrain.com/?_Cl2jbzM
>
> *From what I gather, the order in which the columns are displayed in the grid must match the order of the attribute/value pairs in the JSON"*

I've never used that plugin, but from its example, the order of the columns is defined by the array of objects you provided.

```
columns: [
        { name: 'Album', display: 'Album', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '160px'} },
        { name: 'Artist', display: 'Artist', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100px'} },
        { name: 'Year', display: 'Year', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 4 }, ctrlCss: { width: '40px'} },
        { name: 'Origin', display: 'Origin', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: { 0: '{Choose}', 1: 'Hong Kong', 2: 'Taiwan', 3: 'Japan', 4: 'Korea', 5: 'US', 6: 'Others'} },
        { name: 'Poster', display: 'With Poster?', type: 'checkbox' },
        { name: 'Price', display: 'Price', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 10 }, ctrlCss: { width: '50px', 'text-align': 'right' }, value: 0 },
        { name: 'RecordId', type: 'hidden', value: 0 }
    ]
```

So you can see that the `columns` property is an array of objects that define the columns.

Because it's an Array, it's a well-defined order. The attributes of the columns are defined in each object, so first column will have the name `Albums`, the second will have the name `Artist`, and so on.

Comment: @dandavis: It doesn't. That's the point. The order of columns in the grid is defined by the Array.